# How to avoid repainting of template when i come back to a route in Angularjs Ui-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the current version, when i go from, say a state 'a' to state 'b' and then come back to 'a', the template for 'a' is repainted, instead of restoring the template. Result is that the user-data in template 'a' is lost, as soon as i navigate away from 'a'.

(the problem is there for angular's inbuilt routing service too).

Now, this would be the sole reason i wouldn't like to have ui-router (everything else is fantastic), because this behavior doesn't fit one of our most important use-cases. Also to me personally, this doesn't seem like the most logical of the behaviors.

I wanted to know if there's a way to achieve this using what is built-in.

(I was able to get this behavior after a few hack-arounds in the source code.)

Answer (score 1):

If you app is tracking state across views, there are two ways that i know you persist data across view changes.

1. One is to define the state of view on the parent scope of `ng-view` or `ui-view`. This scope can either be `$rootScope` or a scope that is not change when navigation happens. For example if you define something like `$rootScope.user={};`. Anywhere you inject the $rootScope you would get this user object which you can update.
2. Second is to use a service to track the state of the model that is being worked. For example if you are working on creating user. You can create a service such as `UserCreateWuzard` with method\property such as `userToCreate`. Your controllers would depend upon this service to get and update the active user across views. Since services are singleton by nature you would not loose any data across view.

Comment: That is one of the solutions. But, there are two issues with that :

1. the problem is not tracking data, but it would be the less preferred option.The reason for it being, the HTML is bound to scope,and would keep its state if its hidden on navigation away from the current route/state and unhidden on coming back to the state. I want this behavior which to me seems the most logical way to go about it.


2. It won't scale / computation cost might be too high to repaint the view. 

I think i'll have to write my own routing service, or hack into the source code of existing libraries.

Comment: The first and 2nd options are similar, except in once case data is on rootscope and in second the data is inside a service singleton, which is as good as rootscope.  So there is no reason for any performance or scaling issue. I am not at all talking about view here, so no repainting  not hack, no nothing. The basic idea is to move the model outside the view which manage them. And provide the model to the views through either rootscope or service.

Comment: Ok, i might not have been clear about the use-case earlier, but i just want the state of the UI preserved. Not everything in the current state of UI may be inside the scope (like, for ex. a filled form to be submitted). Now, the solution suggested is assuming everything is in scope.Persisting everything into scope is storing a lot of irrelevant data, when the same behavior can be easily achieved by just hiding or un-hiding the DOM.
 And for the data which is not there in scope, repainting is required.Hence i am a little skeptic about repainting and scalablity .

Comment: Maybe you can add example. For form filled data would always be part of model, that is bounded in the scope, so if you reload the page with the model data from service or rootscope, it would automatically rebind data. ui-view and ng-view destroy and create DOM not hide.

Comment: "ui-view and ng-view destroy and create DOM not hide." is my point exactly. I basically wanted to know if there's away around it. But it seems there's not, so i'll have to see what i can do without using routing.

( http://plnkr.co/edit/BgVUtZ ) is an example, containing some form elements on all the routes/partials. Its not difficult to put the values into scope, but doing that over and over again for 1000 items is not an option. Also forms can be third party, in which case the argument again fails.  

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need of preserving the template. After a little bit of searching I finally ran into this add-on: [UI Router Extras: Sticky State](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky)

Once you've added the library, you will need to update your routes:

```
$stateProvider.state('billing', {
    sticky: true,
    views: {
        'billing' : {
            templateUrl: 'billing.html',
            controller: 'BillingController'
        }
    }
});
```

You'll also need to add a container for the view/template that you need to preserve

```
<main ui-view></main>
<div ui-view="billing" ng-show="$state.current.name==='billing'"></div>
```